# Curved rectangle shape from bottom

Tags: android, shapes

[image: Desired shape]

Is it possible to make this shape for background of components?

Comment: Use canvas for that type of custom views

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using a `<vector>` drawable for this.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFff0000"
        android:pathData="M24 24v-24h-24v24a20 36 0 0 1 24 0z"/>

</vector>
```

Playing around with the first two numbers after the "a" (i.e `a20 36`) will let you control the exact shape of the curve.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can i please know where to make the changes to make the curve upside down?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille do you mean you'd like to flip the whole shape vertically (so that there's a concave curve on the top of the rectangle) or that you'd like to make the curve convex (while still on the bottom of the rectangle)?

Comment: Yes, i want it convex.. so the curve wud be at the bottom but flipped.

Comment: Change the `0 0 1` after `a20 36` to `0 0 0`.

Comment: The problem is that the curve extends off the bottom of the viewport. You'll have to add some `height` and `viewportHeight` to make room.

Comment: Can i reduce the height and width to be able to see it ? if i do, i just need to change the 24 values right?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille convex:
android:pathData="v24h24v-24 a20 36 0 0 1 -24 0z"/>

Answer (score 0):

You should use a nine patch for this image. You can use [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) to generate nine patch from any source created by Roman Nurik.